# Running manim in google colab

Tags: google-colaboratory, manim

I followed the steps in this  [link](https://financial-engineering.medium.com/i-found-a-way-to-run-mamin-on-google-colab-ef37d164c960) and the example in the link works perfectly in google colab. When I try the following code

```
%%manim -qm -v WARNING LinearTransformationSceneExample

class LinearTransformationSceneExample(LinearTransformationScene):
    def __init__(self):
        LinearTransformationScene.__init__(
            self,
            show_coordinates=True,
            leave_ghost_vectors=True,
        )

    def construct(self):
        matrix = [[1, 1], [0, 1]]
        self.apply_matrix(matrix)
        self.wait()
```

It shows the following error
TypeError: LinearTransformationSceneExample.**init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'renderer'

I understand that there is something wrong in this line of code

```
%%manim -qm -v WARNING LinearTransformationSceneExample
```

I am new to manim and there isn't much documentation for reference.
Any help is appreciated.